# How to get all sync adapters (type/authority) for a specific package

Tags: android, package, synchronization, authority

I'm trying to determine the list of `sync adapters` an installed apps provides, but I can't find anything linking a sync authority and the package/app handling it?

Using `AccountManager.getAccountsByType` only provides account, no authority or package information at all.

Using `ContentResolver.getSyncAdapterTypes()` provides all sync authorities available, however I'm unable to determine which `package/app` is handling which.

Is there a way to determine what `sync adapters` a particular `app/package handles` or as in the title, what package handles a given sync adapter?

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was actually pretty easy, I was just taking the whole thing the wrong way, trying to find out the package from a sync adapter, whereas a package has all components defined in its PackageInfo!

Below code will find all package provider being a sync adapter for a given package (pkg_name):

```
            SyncAdapterType[] types = ContentResolver.getSyncAdapterTypes();
            int J = types.length;

            PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo(pkg_name, PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS);
            if (pi.providers != null)
            {
                int I = pi.providers.length;
                for(int i = 0; i < I; i++)
                {
                    ProviderInfo p = pi.providers[i];
                    for(int j = 0; j < J; j++)
                    {
                        SyncAdapterType sat = types[j];

                        if (p.authority.equals(sat.authority))
                        {
                            // This provider is a sync adapter
```

Above code requires a specific permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
```